# ros wiki is down, Do we have any mirror server for that

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros wiki is down, Do we have any mirror server for that

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269962/ros-wiki-is-down,-do-we-have-any-mirror-server-for-that/) by [wnkhattab](https://answers.ros.org/users/31752/wnkhattab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-08-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, multiple in fact.

Try: [mirror-eu.wiki.ros.org](http://mirror-eu.wiki.ros.org/).

---

It does appear that the only listing of mirrors of the wiki is actually on the wiki itself ([wiki/Mirrors](http://wiki.ros.org/Mirrors)), which kind of defeats the purpose. That page is still accessible from the [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:QdGpmH0B_dkJ:wiki.ros.org/Mirrors&num=1&hl=en&gl=nl&strip=1&vwsrc=0) though.

It's also available on the mirrors: [mirror-eu/wiki/Mirrors](http://mirror-eu.wiki.ros.org/Mirrors).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-26**:
Related issue: [ros-infrastructure/roswiki#223](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/223).